# Flutter Http Exception has Occured. _Exception (Exception: Failed Load Data)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want check if Api Url Statuscode is **200** , everything is ok untill in **else** statement . 
I Got this error

```
Exception has occurred.
_Exception (Exception: Failed Load Data)
```

It's My Code Api

```
Future<List<Mosque>> getMahasiswaById(String id) async {
  var baseURL=Urls.BASE_API_URL;
  var apiRespon = await http.get('$baseURL/mahasiswa/get/id/$id');
  if(apiRespon.statusCode == 200) {
    final apiResponJson = json.decode(apiRespon.body);
    print(apiResponJson);
    return (apiResponJson['data'] as List).map((p)=>Mosque.fromJson(p)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed Load Data');
  }
}
```

How can i fix this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

always use try and catch with http requests it'll help you to identify the source of the exception , you can do something like that :

```
Future<List<Mosque>> getMahasiswaById(String id) async{
    var baseURL=Urls.BASE_API_URL;
    try{
    var apiRespon = await http.get('$baseURL/mahasiswa/get/id/$id');
   if(apiRespon.statusCode == 200){
      final apiResponJson = json.decode(apiRespon.body);
      print(apiResponJson);
      return (apiResponJson['data'] as List).map((p)=>Mosque.fromJson(p)).toList();
      }
     else {
         print(apiReson.statusCode.toString());
         throw Exception('Failed load data with status code ${apiReson.statusCode}');   
   }
  catch(e){ 
       print (e); 
       throw e;}
 }
```

most of the time the exceptions come from bad internet connection , issue in the back end or lost in the internet connection ,when you use the above code it'll print out the type of the exception so you can identify the root of the error.
I hope that can help